# Probability that one proportion is greater than another by a value

Tags: probability, statistics

I am looking at two samples of independent binomialy distributed variables $X \sim Bin(n,p_1)$ and $Y \sim Bin(n,p_2)$.

I need to test the hypotheses $H_0: p_1-p_2 \geq d$ vs $H_a: p_1-p_2 \leq d$. More specifically, I am looking for an expression for exact $P(p_1-p_2 \geq d | H_0 \text{ true})$.

I have come across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216746/probability-one-proportion-is-greater-than-another) which could be exactly what I need, except that I am baffled by the condition that this probability has to be evaluated under the null. How do we decide which of the two distributions is the null distribution? How do we adapt the answer to the question above to meet this condition? Thank you.

Comment: $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not random variable, so the probability you want is not well defined (unless you are in bayesian setting and parameters have priors). Maybe what you are looking for is $P(X_1/n - X_2/n \geq d | H_0\text{ true})$. Still, even this probability may well depend on $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: Presumably you have data: In Group 1 $X_1$ successes in $n_1$ trials so that $\hat p_1 = X_1/n_1.$ Similarly for Group 2. Then use an approach similar to [this one](https://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/05d2pops.html).